# Routing from express works but not from React js react-router

Tags: react-router

In my webpack, the entry point of the application is set to `index.js`:

```
entry: {  
    app: [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      './client/index.js'
    ]
```

In node Js, For path `/` in my application, I am routing it to `index.html`
from `routes.js` on server side using:

```
 app.route('/*')
    .get((req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.resolve(`${app.get('appPath')}/index.html`));
    });
```

Above code understandably serves index.html.

But what if I wanted my application routing to be initialized  using `React-router`?

index.html gets rendered but I don't see `index.js` getting initialized at all.It is defined as entry point in webpack so that should happen ,right?

**Problem:** To have React-routing initialized which should work once the flow gets to `index.js`

My `routes.js` in client folder looks like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import About from './components/About/About';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Outlet from './components/Home/SelectOutlet';

console.log("routes file client")

    export default (
      <Route path="/" component={Header}>
        <IndexRoute component={Outlet}/>
        <Route path="about" component={Footer}/>
      </Route>
    );
```

and `index.js`

```
import 'babel-polyfill';  //certain functions like array.from , set, map can't be transpiled by babel so ue poyfill for that
import React from 'react';
import {  render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import  routes  from './routes';
//import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';  //webpack can import CSS files too
import './styles/styles.css';

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}/>),
  document.getElementById('app')
);

console.log("In index js render ")
```

Consoles in `index.js` and `routes.js` never get consoled and the application just serves `index.html` because of express routing

my webpack file is taken from here: https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter

but I don't see `bundle.js` getting created anywhere with npm start command.

Edit:
error screenshot:
**screen 1:**
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2a8d.png)

When I click on this error message:

I get all the content from html in js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <title>
            ABC
        </title>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h1> XYZ</h1>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="index.js"></script> 

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... Are you including

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

in your index.html?...

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I got unexpected symbol <! from index.html in console at line one of index.js. When I click on this file in console, it says 'index.js' and shows whatever I have in index.html. @kevin

Comment: You'll definitely need to include that script in your index.html though, you'll need to fix that error though. Can you be more specific with your error? Or show a screenshot of it

Comment: Ah now I see what the problem is, good that you also updated the HTML code part. You are including the script with src="./index.js", that dot is used in files that need to be transpiled by webpack to specify the root folder. Try leaving that dot away and look again at my first answer, also I can see your opening script tag has 2 ">", check that also. Just copy my answer and paste it over your script tag.

Comment: It is there now ,corrected it but still get the same error

Comment: Any errors in your terminal? Where you run your server / webpack?

Comment: I see, it is happening because it is not able to find the js file. Not sure why though.index.js lies right next to index.html in the very same folder.

Comment: Same error: uncaugh syntax error . If I write a random js file name, I get the same error. It isn't able to find the file somehow.Just this error in web console. Nothing else